# Equivalent for "at the heart of our society"

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to say "XXX is at the heart of our society," but I feel it's such a cliche!   Any suggestions for a somewhat equivalent sentence?

Comment: If you provide the context of this sentence, e.g. where it's going to be used, we might help you a teeny weeny bit better

Comment: @thursagen Its in the introduction section of a chapter. I want to open up by saying an equivalent sentence and then provide the reason why xxxx is so important...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

> XXX is an integral part of our soceity/family/group! He's...he's indispensable!

Comment: Or "XXX is integral to our society".